# How do I switch characters in the overworld?

Tags: steamworld-quest

When I first started SteamWorld Quest I was playing as Armilly in the overworld. At some point during Act 1 I somehow switched to controlling Copernica instead. Initially I thought the overworld character I play as might be chapter-specific, but I was still controlling Copernica even when replaying earlier stages with chapter select.

How did I start controlling Copernica instead of Armilly on the overworld? How do I switch my character back?

[image: Controlling Copernica in Act 1 Chapter 1]